# Svg rectangle with triangular / rounded end for progress bar

Tags: html, css, svg

I am working on an svg based progress bar that needs to match image below. I am having trouble achieving that triangular / rounded look on the right end. I initially tried this with path and got the shape I wanted, but with path it was hard to make it responsive (height and width need to be changeable easily). It also needs to change width based on progress, although this could be achieved by just shifting whole path / rect to the left and hiding overflow.

Hence I wanted to ask if there is any simple method to achieve this with simple svg shapes like rect, so it is easier to work with and not rely on complex path strings.

html and css can be used here to achieve this shape as well.

For reference this is how path implementation looks (note that triangle on the end has slightly rounded end and edges)

```html
<svg width="432px" height="39px" viewBox="0 0 432 39">
    <path d="M0.0724087765,38.0710052 L0.0724087765,0.0965500345 C275.055657,0.053915002 413.031521,0.053915002 414,0.0965500345 C415.452719,0.160502583 431.378608,16.7041591 431.378608,19.0837776 C431.378608,21.4633961 415.356767,38.0112767 414,38.0710052 C413.095489,38.1108242 275.119625,38.1108242 0.0724087765,38.0710052 Z" fill="red"></path>
</svg>
```

**Image example**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify the SVG to keep only the triangle part then integrate it inside background where you can easily color the remaining part using a simple gradient:

```css
.box {
 background:
   url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64'><path d='M0 64 C40 56 64 44 64 34 C64 20 40 8 0 0 Z' fill='red' /></svg>") right/auto 100%,
   linear-gradient(red,red) left/calc(100% - 40px) 100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 height:40px;
 margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="width:200px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="width:100px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="width:50px;"></div>



<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64' width=40>
  <path d='M0 64 C40 56 64 44 64 34 C64 20 40 8 0 0 Z'fill='green' />
</svg>
```

In case you want a gradient coloration you can use the SVG as mask:

```css
.box {
 -webkit-mask:
   url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64'><path d='M0 64 C40 56 64 44 64 34 C64 20 40 8 0 0 Z' fill='red' /></svg>") right/auto 100%,
   linear-gradient(red,red) left/calc(100% - 40px) 100%;
 -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
 mask:
   url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64'><path d='M0 64 C40 56 64 44 64 34 C64 20 40 8 0 0 Z' fill='red' /></svg>") right/auto 100%,
   linear-gradient(red,red) left/calc(100% - 40px) 100%;
 mask-repeat:no-repeat;
 
 background:linear-gradient(blue,yellow);
 height:40px;
 margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="width:200px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="width:100px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="width:50px;"></div>



<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64' width=40>
  <path d='M0 64 C40 56 64 44 64 34 C64 20 40 8 0 0 Z'fill='green' />
</svg>
```

I used a random SVG to illustrate, feel free to change it with your own:

Comment: Nice, didn't think about it this way